# orthogonal complement problem: show $\operatorname{oc}(A\cap B)=\operatorname{oc}(A)+\operatorname{oc}(B)$

Tags: linear-algebra

$A$ and $B$ are subspaces of $V$, a finite-dimensional inner product space.

Show that $$\operatorname{oc}(A\cap B)=\operatorname{oc}(A)+\operatorname{oc}(B)$$

Comment: Can you show your efforts?

Comment: @egreg does the proof basically follow up as such? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Negation_of_a_conjunction . The wiki page uses U which can practically be replaced by + here. I'm also given another problem actually (which i've proved) and i've toyed with the idea of deducing this result from  what i have proved but that hasn't been fruitful. here is the other part: oc(M+N) = oc(M) intersection oc(N)

Answer (score 0):

It can be trivially proved that,
$$A^{\bot} + B^{\bot} \subseteq (A \cap B)^{\bot}$$

Thanks to egreg for pointing out that $A$ and $B$ are subspaces, I missed that part. Here are some hints to show:
$$(A \cap B)^{\bot} \subseteq A^{\bot} + B^{\bot}$$

Hint:

1. Consider some basis for $V$ and "assign" some to $A$ and $B$
2. What is basis for $A^{\bot}$, $B^{\bot}$, $A \cap B$ and $(A \cap B)^{\bot}$?

Comment: In the question $A$ and $B$ are subspaces of $V$, yours aren't.

Comment: Oh I missed the part of $A$ and $B$ being subspaces. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We can indeed use the fact that
$$
\operatorname{oc}(A+B)=\operatorname{oc}(A)\cap\operatorname{oc}(B)
$$

If we know this relation (for all subspaces $A$ and $B$), we can say that
$$
\operatorname{oc}(\operatorname{oc}(A)+\operatorname{oc}(B))=
\operatorname{oc}(\operatorname{oc}(A))\cap\operatorname{oc}(\operatorname{oc}(B))=
A\cap B$$
because on a finite dimensional space
$$
\operatorname{oc}(\operatorname{oc}(A))=A
$$
for every subspace $A$.

Then…